# Node: http module, cannot change timeout for connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, timeout

I have a problem with setting a timeout per connection with the http module.

My code is the following:

```
server = require('http').createServer(function(req,res) {
   res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
   res.end('Hello World!');
}).listen(1089);

server.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('socket opened');

    socket.on('close', function () {
        console.log('socket closed');
    });

   // Extend socket lifetime
   socket.setTimeout(120000, () => {
       console.log('Timeout socket');
   });
});
```

Theoretically, if I open a keep-alive connection, it should get closed after 120 seconds of inactivity.

Using netcat I get the correct output:

```
echo -e "GET /test HTTP/1.1\nConnection: keep-alive\n\n" | netcat -C -q -1 localhost 1089


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Wed, 10 Jul 2019 00:12:50 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

c
Hello World!
0
```

And I also get the correct output in the terminal:

```
socket opened
Timeout socket
socket closed
```

The only problem is that it closes the connection after only a few seconds instead of 120. I already tried a lot of things but I can't find any way to change this in order to achieve the timeout of 120 seconds.

Interestingly, opening `http://localhost:1089/` with Chrome (not with Firefox, it opens just one connection which gets closed after a few seconds), it opens two connections of which the first gets closed after a few seconds but the second stays open for the 120 seconds.

But if I open two connections at once from two terminals with netcat both get closed after a few seconds.

I also tried three ways of adding

```
server.setTimeout(120000, () => {
   console.log('server timeout');
});
```

to the code:

1. Just adding it after creating the server: Nothing changed, the output of both timeouts print at the same moment.
2. Commenting the socket timeout: The same behaviour, only that it now just triggers the server timeout.
3. Commenting the whole `server.on('connection')` part: Same as above.

Comment: I tested the Node.js code in question with visiting `http://localhost:1089/` in browser. As browser sends 2 HTTP requests (one for `GET /` and another for `GET /favicon.ico`) with 2 connections, I find one connection timeout after a few seconds, while another timeout after 120 seconds -- wish this information helps.

Comment: Have you tried using [`server.setTimeout([msecs][, callback])`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_settimeout_msecs_callback)?

Comment: @shaochuancs: Thank you. I tried it with Chrome and Firefox and here it happens only with Chrome. I updated the question.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, thank you. It has the same behaviour. I updated the question.